# Add iCloud to Windows 10 Explorer sidebar / navigation pane

Tags: windows-10, icloud

I would like to add an iCloud link to my Windows 10 sidebar / navigation pane.
Normally, when you install iCloud for Windows it will add iCloud to the "Quick Access" submenu.

I would like to add iCloud to the same level as "Quick Access", "This Computer" and "Dropbox".

I have found multiple how-to's for ownCloud/Nextcloud and Google Drive, but not one for iCloud.

Comment: I guess that we can do this by add the SID of ICloud, add the key in the registry path: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID`(as the quick access, This PC and other items are all in this path), But I don't know how to get the SID of ICloud.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Somebody else who can tell us how to get the SID of the icloud (software)?

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to find CLSID for iCloud Drive, so I´ve created my own CLSID key and I used the procedure in this page to create a custom entry in Navigation Pane:
[Creating a Link in the Left Pane of the File Explorer - like OneDrive or DropBox](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1116313/Creating-a-Link-in-the-Left-Pane-of-the-File-Explo)

Here it is an screenshot of the result:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fhEb.png)

To make things easier, here you have the REG file I created, just copy and paste the content in notepad and save it as a .reg file, then import it into the registry:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{71BC9222-EF55-4021-A112-D3AE53BD3C15}]
@="iCloud Drive" "System.IsPinnedToNamespaceTree"=dword:00000001
"SortOrderIndex"=dword:00000042

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{71BC9222-EF55-4021-A112-D3AE53BD3C15}\DefaultIcon]
@=hex(2):25,00,43,00,6f,00,6d,00,6d,00,6f,00,6e,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,\
00,61,00,6d,00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,25,00,5c,00,41,00,70,00,70,00,\
6c,00,65,00,5c,00,49,00,6e,00,74,00,65,00,72,00,6e,00,65,00,74,00,20,00,53,\
00,65,00,72,00,76,00,69,00,63,00,65,00,73,00,5c,00,41,00,50,00,4c,00,5a,00,\
4f,00,44,00,36,00,34,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,30,00,00,\
00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{71BC9222-EF55-4021-A112-D3AE53BD3C15}\InProcServer32]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,59,00,53,00,54,00,45,00,4d,00,52,00,4f,00,4f,00,54,00,25,\
00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,73,00,68,00,\
65,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,00,00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{71BC9222-EF55-4021-A112-D3AE53BD3C15}\Instance]
"CLSID"="{0E5AAE11-A475-4c5b-AB00-C66DE400274E}"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{71BC9222-EF55-4021-A112-D3AE53BD3C15}\Instance\InitPropertyBag]
"Attributes"=dword:00000011
"TargetFolderPath"=hex(2):25,00,75,00,73,00,65,00,72,00,70,00,72,00,6f,00,66,\
00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,25,00,5c,00,69,00,43,00,6c,00,6f,00,75,00,64,00,44,00,\
72,00,69,00,76,00,65,00,00,00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{71BC9222-EF55-4021-A112-D3AE53BD3C15}\ShellFolder]
"FolderValueFlags"=dword:00000028 "Attributes"=dword:f080004d

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{71BC9222-EF55-4021-A112-D3AE53BD3C15}]
@="iCloud Drive" "System.IsPinnedToNamespaceTree"=dword:00000001
"SortOrderIndex"=dword:00000042

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{71BC9222-EF55-4021-A112-D3AE53BD3C15}\DefaultIcon]
@=hex(2):25,00,43,00,6f,00,6d,00,6d,00,6f,00,6e,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,\
00,61,00,6d,00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,25,00,5c,00,41,00,70,00,70,00,\
6c,00,65,00,5c,00,49,00,6e,00,74,00,65,00,72,00,6e,00,65,00,74,00,20,00,53,\
00,65,00,72,00,76,00,69,00,63,00,65,00,73,00,5c,00,41,00,50,00,4c,00,5a,00,\
4f,00,44,00,36,00,34,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,30,00,00,\
00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{71BC9222-EF55-4021-A112-D3AE53BD3C15}\InProcServer32]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,59,00,53,00,54,00,45,00,4d,00,52,00,4f,00,4f,00,54,00,25,\
00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,73,00,68,00,\
65,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,00,00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{71BC9222-EF55-4021-A112-D3AE53BD3C15}\Instance]
"CLSID"="{0E5AAE11-A475-4c5b-AB00-C66DE400274E}"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{71BC9222-EF55-4021-A112-D3AE53BD3C15}\Instance\InitPropertyBag]
"Attributes"=dword:00000011
"TargetFolderPath"=hex(2):25,00,75,00,73,00,65,00,72,00,70,00,72,00,6f,00,66,\
00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,25,00,5c,00,69,00,43,00,6c,00,6f,00,75,00,64,00,44,00,\
72,00,69,00,76,00,65,00,00,00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{71BC9222-EF55-4021-A112-D3AE53BD3C15}\ShellFolder]
"FolderValueFlags"=dword:00000028 "Attributes"=dword:f080004d

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel]
"{71BC9222-EF55-4021-A112-D3AE53BD3C15}"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\{71BC9222-EF55-4021-A112-D3AE53BD3C15}]
@="iCloud Drive"
```

Comment: The above fix is the answer, but I had to manually search for the string "iCloud" in regedit and find these keys to delete them. This is especially frustrating with the Windows 10 installed version of the program, since that seems to not remove registry keys when it uninstalls or reinstalls, meaning it changes the UUID of the key each time, so you have 2, then 4, then 6 etc. of the iCloud Photos / iCloud Drive folders each time you decide to save space and uninstall iCloud for Windows and reinstall later. Because think Apple. :^)

Answer (score 1):

Install iCloud from Microsoft Store in Windows 10 will give you iCloud link on the navigation pane with the same level as that of One Drive.

Install iCloud from  website into Windows 10 will just give you iCloud link at ‘Quick Access’ section of the navigation pane only.

https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204283